# RDP and freerdp over IPv6

Tags: remote-desktop, ipv6

My question is how we can use this RDP and freerdp protocols with IPv6.These protocols support IPv6 or these protocol only support ipv4.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the **IPv6** address in **square brackets**.

So for **IPv6** address `fd94:8414:eef6:325d::c0a8:1302` and port 45001, you would use `[fd94:8414:eef6:325d::c0a8:1302]:45001`

[Source:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/da151755-edd1-4a54-b9ff-083acf023e06/remote-desktop-connection-using-ipv6-address-and-custom-port?forum=winserverTS)

Comment: its not working with rdp.Did you check with that

Comment: Yeah it did work, try this please: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469764.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: redsktop [fd94:8414:eef6:325d::c0a8:1302]:45001